# How to resolve the Cypress error "No Specs Found"

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

In my Cypress testing suite, I'm getting the following issue and I'm not understanding how to fix it. I understood is a path issue but cannot figure out what should be the right path. The issue is only with my smoke test but the rest of my scopes is working fine.

[image: error message]

I'm not sure what is wrong here, probably I configured the paths wrong but whatever I do seems not working.

The spec files are existing and there are configured as follows in a `smoke.json` file

```json
{
  "specPattern": [
    "authentication/log-in.cy.js",
    "candidate/study-sign-up.cy.js",
    "candidate/click-all-tabs.cy.js"
  ]
}
```

The folder structure is as follows

[image: folder structure]

Details on the CY configuration

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    viewportWidth: 1280,
    viewportHeight: 800,
    screenshotsFolder: 'artifacts',
    video: false,
    reporter: 'junit',
    reporterOptions: {
      mochaFile: 'results/test-results-[hash].xml',
    },
    retries: 1,
    defaultCommandTimeout: 60000,

    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config);
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: how do the other scopes differ in terms of the path?

Comment: I found the issue if I add **/ before the path now it is working